# Custom frame title in Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, title

I'm using Emacs and I find quite annoying the default frame (aka window) title that is `user@host` especially when I have several frames opened. Searching around I found that it's possible to change that by editing the variable `frame-title-format`; so I did it, I changed it to `"%b"` (for example) and that worked.

**Now the issue:** after exactly 30 seconds I minimized the frame the title switches back to `user@host` until I focus again on the frame.

I tried to write in my `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq frame-title-format "%b")
```

and I even tried to customize it:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ; [...]
 '(frame-title-format "%b")
)
```

with no luck.

**DETAILS:**

- GNU Emacs 23.2.1
- Debian Squeeze
- Openbox

Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using, under what operating system? Can you reproduce this behavior with a `.emacs` that only contains `(setq frame-title-format "%b")`?

Comment: Edited. Yes, it's the same with a `~/.emacs` that only contains `(setq frame-title-format "%b")`.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce the problem, or does it happen randomly “after a while”? What is your window manager or desktop environment (not that I think it should matter)? (By the way, yes, it should work the way you think, and it does for me with Emacs 23.1.1 on Ubuntu.)

Comment: Surprisingly, "after a while" = 30 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(setq frame-title-format "%b")
(setq icon-title-format "%b")
```

And it works for me (GNU Emacs 23.1.1).

If it continues to not work for you, try running a plain-vanilla emacs session (`emacs -q --no-site-init`), then add the above two lines and then try it.  If it works then something in your .emacs file (or the site-wide .emacs file) is in conflict.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that worked! For some reason after a while `icon-title-format` is used rather than `frame-title-format`; setting both to the same value solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
(modify-frame-parameters (selected-frame) (list (cons 'name "The New Title")))
```

does the trick for me.

Comment: Yes thanks, it does the trick but this way I cannot have the same behavior of "%b": shows the current buffer.